# No data binding on form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm migrating a ASP.NET 5 app to ASP.NET core. Everything is going well except that I can't submit a form.

When I do, looking at the Chrome's network timeline, the controller URL is reached (/MyController/Create) but nothing happens (The browser is idling, waiting).

After looking for some explanations: trying to call a parameterless controller works fine. Adding [FromForm] returns a 415. [FromData] idle too...

I can't find anything on the internet. Here too! (For the first time during my entire life).

NB: Everything was working fine using ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. Same code on both side.

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SocieteGroupe societeGroupe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.SocieteGroupe.Add(societeGroupe);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewData["Id_Devise"] = new SelectList(_context.Devise, "Id", "Code_ISO", societeGroupe.Id_Devise);
        return View(PackageUtils.GetViewPath(viewPath, OperationType.CREATE), societeGroupe);
    }
```

And my view :

```
<form asp-controller="SocieteGroupes" asp-action="Create">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>SocieteGroupe</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id_Devise" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Id_Devise" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Id_Devise"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id_Salesforce" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Id_Salesforce" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Id_Salesforce" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Nom" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Nom" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Nom" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does someone already faced out this problem or got an idea about it?

EDIT:

Instead of using a complexe type as parameter. I tried (for debug purposes) to use a string instead and return the string in Json format in order to debug it. Whatever I use (nothing, [FromForm], [FromBody]...), the result is null. I don't know what to do next. Any help will be appreciated :D

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ru using RC2 .net core (ie the most current .net core available as of now)?

Comment: Yes. We downloaded it from the official repository on last friday and reinstalled it today in order to see if the problem is solved. But it's not :/

Comment: ok you mentioned reinstall so am assuming you have upgraded from RC1 or some other pre-release version. Are you able to try on a 'clean' PC that hasnt had RC-x installed prior? Secondly, something else to try would be to start a *new* RC2 project and add in just that piece of code and see what happens. at this stage am just guessing but this would be my first steps

Comment: I've already uninstall RC1 and then reinstalled RC2. Still not working

Comment: `Are you able to try on a 'clean' PC that hasnt had RC-x installed prior?  Secondly, something else to try would be to start a new RC2 project and add in just that piece of code and see what happens`

Comment: I followed your advices: I does not work either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. This is a known bug of RC2.

According this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4666), you need to download this [file](https://gist.github.com/rynowak/9488b3b1a6b81876d8b14de72feb0857) and put it wherever you want in your project. Then you just need, in Startup.cs to add the line `services.AddSingleton<IModelBinderFactory, MyModelBinderFactory>();`

And that's all! For me, it worked :D